# Configuring OpenVPN server (Debian 8) and client (Windows 10)

Tags: openvpn, webmin

I'm having trouble configuring OpenVPN server on Debian 8 and client on Windows 10 (64 bit). When trying to connect I get a fatal error on the client side.

Server log:

```
Fri Mar 25 09:25:34 2016 OpenVPN 2.3.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] b$  
Fri Mar 25 09:25:34 2016 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015, LZO 2.08
Fri Mar 25 09:25:34 2016 WARNING: file 'keys/mycawebmin/myserverwebmin.key' is group or others accessible
Fri Mar 25 09:25:34 2016 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Fri Mar 25 09:25:34 2016 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Fri Mar 25 09:25:34 2016 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Fri Mar 25 09:25:34 2016 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.50.0.1 peer 10.50.0.2
Fri Mar 25 09:25:34 2016 GID set to nogroup
Fri Mar 25 09:25:34 2016 UID set to nobody
Fri Mar 25 09:25:34 2016 UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]
Fri Mar 25 09:25:34 2016 UDPv4 link remote: [undef]
Fri Mar 25 09:25:34 2016 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

Client log:

```
Fri Mar 25 10:34:39 2016 OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [IPv6] built on Mar 10 2016
Fri Mar 25 10:34:39 2016 Windows version 6.2 (Windows 8 or greater)
Fri Mar 25 10:34:39 2016 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1s  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.09
Enter Management Password:
Fri Mar 25 10:34:39 2016 MANAGEMENT: Socket bind failed on local address [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340: Address already in use (WSAEADDRINUSE)
Fri Mar 25 10:34:39 2016 Exiting due to fatal error
```

Server configuration file:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun0
ca keys/mycawebmin/ca.crt
cert keys/mycawebmin/myserverwebmin.crt
key keys/mycawebmin/myserverwebmin.key
dh keys/mycawebmin/dh2048.pem
server 10.50.0.0 255.255.255.0
crl-verify keys/mycawebmin/crl.pem
ifconfig-pool-persist servers/MyVPNWebmin/logs/ipp.txt
cipher DES-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
status servers/MyVPNWebmin/logs/openvpn-status.log
log-append servers/MyVPNWebmin/logs/openvpn.log
verb 2
mute 20
max-clients 100
keepalive 10 120
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/servers/MyVPNWebmin/ccd
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
ccd-exclusive
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
```

Client configuration file:

```
client
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
dh dh2048.pem
cert myclientwebmin.crt
key myclientwebmin.key
remote 192.158.31.146 1194
cipher DES-CBC
verb 2
mute 20
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
float
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
```

I used webmin for the setup. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: '127.0.0.1:25340: Address already in use (WSAEADDRINUSE)' you should check the port with netstat utility